# How to remove a object from array and push to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

can someone help me with some code to splice an array and push to new array. I have an arrays

```
someArray = [{
  name: "Kristian",
  lines: "2,5,10"
}, {
  name: "John",
  lines: "1,19,26,96"
}, {
  name: "Kristian",
  lines: "2,58,160"
}, {
  name: "Felix",
  lines: "1,19,26,96"
}];
```

i want to splice where name = to Kristian and push to a new array

Comment: You should first post code demonstrating your attempt at this. Then we can help you with that code, or show you how it ought to be done

Comment: [Solution with just `forEach`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg73hbok/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

[Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

```js
var someArray = [{name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"},{name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"},{name:"Kristian", lines:"2,58,160"},{name:"Felix", lines:"1,19,26,96"}];

var res = someArray.filter((p,i) => {
  if(p.name=="Kristian"){
    someArray.splice(i, 1); //remove the mached object from the original array
    return p;
  }
});

console.log(res);
console.log('----------------');
console.log(someArray);
```

Comment: does not remove ...

Comment: @Mamun: i've tried the fliter already the thing is i want to push the removed item to a new array

Comment: @jack, `res` is indeed a new array..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce()` method along-with `.splice()`:

```js
let data = [
  {name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"}, {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"},
  {name:"Kristian", lines:"2,58,160"}, {name:"Felix", lines:"1,19,26,96"}
];
  
let result = data.reduce((r, c, i, a) => {
  if(c.name = 'Kristian')
    r.push(a.splice(i, 1));
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mixture of `filter` and `map`:

```
const filtered = someArray.filter(obj => obj.name !== "Kristian")
const newArray = someArray.map(obj => obj.name === "Kristian")
```

Filtered will remove the items whilst map will create a new array with the removed items